# Becoming a "stubborn and rebellious child" - a question on Tosafot Yom Tov

Tags: mishna, maaser-tithes, maseches-sanhedrin

In the Mishna (Sanhedrin 8:2), one of the circumstances under which a child who consumed a certain amount of meat and wine does *not* become a "stubborn and rebellious child" (בן סורר ומורה) is when the food that he consumed is either *tevel* (food from which *terumot* have not been taken), *maaser rishon* from which *terumat hamaaser* has not been taken, unredeemed *maaser sheni* (outside Jerusalem) or unredeemed *heqdesh*. Tosafot Yom Tov comments that this section doesn't belong here, since one only becomes a "stubborn and rebellious child" if one consumes, specifically, meat and wine.

I don't understand this statement. Wine could potentially be any one of those items in the above list, while meat could potentially be unredeemed *heqdesh*. What is the Tosafot Yom Tov's problem with this passage?

Answer (score 1):

The Tosafos Yom Tov understands the words "achal...maaser sheni v'hekdesh" literally to refer to eating as opposed to drinking.  The meat cannot be maaser sheni. (See Tiferes Yisrael).

Comment: As I understand the phrase (which appears a dozen-or-so times in Seder Zeraim), "מעשר שני והקדש שלא נפדו" means maaser sheni that has not been redeemed *or* heqdesh that has not been redeemed - and not something that is both maaser sheni and heqdesh at the same time. Are you suggesting otherwise?

Comment: @ShimonbM No. I am not suggesting otherwise. I am suggesting (as per Artscroll's Yad Avraham commentary) that the two possible non-ben-sorer-umore foods refer literally to food; i.e. meat just as the other preceding usages of "achal" refer to literal eating and not drinking, such as treifos, shkatzim, and r'massim.